# How to access $window in a Provider?

Tags: angularjs

I'd like to access `$window` from a provider (`mymodule.provider(...)`) **BUT** I need such dependency at config time (so it's no use for me to put such dependency in the `$get`).

Currently I don't access `$window`, and the reason I need such dependency in config time is because I need to access `$window.STATIC_URL`, which is a constant in the window, and I use it to configure the states' templates (`$stateProvider`).

Current code is:

```
mymodule.provider('StaticUrl', function() {
    this.url = function() { return window.STATIC_URL || 'static'; };
    this.$get = this.url;
});
```

This is because I need such value in both config and run time (I use it for more than just setting up the states, so when I need such url in a controller, I import it as a dependency).

```
//config
mymodule.config(['StaticUrlProvider', '$stateProvider', function(sup, $sp){
    //...
    $sp.state('main', {
        templateUrl: sup.url() + 'path/to/template.html'
    });
    //...
}]);
//run-time (in this case: a controller)
mymodule.controller('MyController', ['$scope', 'StaticUrl', function($s, su) {
    var buildingType = /*a complex expression here*/;
    $s.buildingPicture = $su + 'path/to/building/pics/' + buildingType + '.png';
}]);
```

Given an existing dataset, I have a picture for each entry, located under STATIC_URL, which must be provided. So this means I use such constant in both stages.

How would I do it in a more Angular-way (**i.e. without relying in globals**)? Is there a way I can access `$window` from a provider without raising a `moduleerr`?

Comment: try injecting $windowProvider

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Inject `$windowProvider` and call `$windowProvider.$get()`

Comment: I initially thought that i could use `$get('myprop')` but really it returns the entire window object.